# Dynamic Width Slides?

Tags: jssor

I'm using a JSSOR slider that scrolls content horizontally. My issue is that the slide content is dynamic. An admin has the ability to add and remove images & text from the slider, however not all the divs are the same width. This creates gaps and/or overlapping.

I can create a code to get the width of each slide prior to the initialization of jssor, however I'm wondering if there's a way to apply $SlideWidth to individual slides by index?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you make the images a background and set it to cover?

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't always images, I should have specified that. 90% of the time it is an image, however sometimes they place text announcements there as well.

Comment: Are you pulling slide content like image URLs and text from a database?

Comment: Yes. The slider is a "news" slider, and it was originally to be used for thumbnails to full articles, however now theyre putting other images there as well as text announcements. It all comes from a news db.

Comment: For now, there is no option to set different width for each individual slide.

Comment: I appreciate your response! I was able to replicate what I was trying to do by grouping all the "different sized slides" into one big slide. Since this wouldn't scroll (as it was just one slide), I just duplicated it. Worked like a charm.